# sending Post on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-widget

I have to send a link on user's facebook wall.  I am trying but not getting success.
I wrote the code but its not working. First i write:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FacebookActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Facebook face;
    AsyncFacebookRunner run;
    String[] permission=new String[] {"publish_stream", 
            "read_stream", "offline_access"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        face=new Facebook("my key");
        run=new AsyncFacebookRunner(face);
        face.authorize(this, permission,new MyLoginDialogListener());

    }
    private final class MyLoginDialogListener implements com.facebook.android
    .Facebook.DialogListener {

public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

    Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this, "Ho Gya Authorize",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    run=new AsyncFacebookRunner(face);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("message", " hello");
    bundle.putString("name", "hello");
    bundle.putString("description", "Hello");
    bundle.putString("link", "http://www.facebook.com");
     try {
        face.request("me/feed",bundle, "POST");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // here enable logout
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}
public void onError(DialogError error) {}
public void onCancel() {}
}


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        face.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Please suggest how to proceed further. My code is not posting on the wall of user's wall.

Comment: You need to be more specific about "not working". Are you asking if anyone would debug your entire program for you, first to figure out *what* isn't working, and then how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for posting wall on facebook

```
  public class AndroidFacebookSample extends Activity {

private static final String FACEBOOK_APPID = "PUT YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID HERE";
private static final String FACEBOOK_PERMISSION = "publish_stream";
private static final String TAG = "FacebookSample";
private static final String MSG = "Message from FacebookSample";

private final Handler mFacebookHandler = new Handler();
private TextView loginStatus;
private FacebookConnector facebookConnector;

final Runnable mUpdateFacebookNotification = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Facebook updated !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector(FACEBOOK_APPID, this, getApplicationContext(), new String[] {FACEBOOK_PERMISSION});


    loginStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_status);
    Button tweet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
    Button clearCredentials = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear_credentials);

    tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            postMessage();
        }
    });

    clearCredentials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearCredentials();
            updateLoginStatus();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    this.facebookConnector.getFacebook().authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateLoginStatus();
}

public void updateLoginStatus() {
    loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid());
}


private String getFacebookMsg() {
    return MSG + " at " + new Date().toLocaleString();
}   

public void postMessage() {

    if (facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
        postMessageInThread();
    } else {
        SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthSucceed() {
                postMessageInThread();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthFail(String error) {

            }
        };
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);
        facebookConnector.login();
    }
}

private void postMessageInThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                facebookConnector.postMessageOnWall(getFacebookMsg());
                mFacebookHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error sending msg",ex);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

private void clearCredentials() {
    try {
        facebookConnector.getFacebook().logout(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}